# Django CustomUserModel & Form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

After submitting the sign-up form in my Django application, I want to register a User. I want the username to be the email address provided in the form.

To do this I create a CostumUser model, to manage this model I also created a CustomUserManager. see my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.utils import timezone

from .choices import GENDER_CHOICE
# Create your models here.
class CostumUserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def _create_user(self, email, firstName, lastName, gender, password, **extra_fields):
    """
    Create and save a user with the given email, password, firstname, lastname and gender
    """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("The given Email must be set")
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email,
                      first_name=firstName,
                      last_name=lastName,
                      gender=gender,
                      )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, firstName, lastName, gender, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, firstName, lastName, gender, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, firstName, lastName, gender, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, firstName, lastName, gender, password, **extra_fields)


class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    #CostumUserManager
    objects = CostumUserManager()
    #CostumUser fields in db.
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices= GENDER_CHOICE)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
    _('staff status'),
    default=False,
    help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.'),
)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
    _('active'),
    default=True,
    help_text=_(
        'Designates whether this user should be treated as active. '
        'Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'
    ),
)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email' #Email used as username
    #define required fields
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name','last_name','gender']

    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    def is_actif(self):
        return self.actif
```

I also created a CustomUserCreationForm. see forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser

from .choices import GENDER_CHOICE

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=40,
                            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'required':True,#set attributes
                                                          'class':'form-control',
                                                          'placeholder':'First Name *',
                                                          })
                            )
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=40,
                           widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'required':True,#set attributes
                                                          'class':'form-control',
                                                          'placeholder':'Last Name *',
                                                          })
                          )
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254,
                         widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'required':True,#set attributes
                                                        'class':'form-control',
                                                        'placeholder':'Your Email *',
                                                        })
                         )
    gender = forms.ChoiceField (choices=GENDER_CHOICE,
                            widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control',
                                                        }),
                            initial='Male',
                            )
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'required':True,#set attributes
                                                        'class':'form-control',
                                                        'placeholder':'Password *',
                                                        }),
                            strip=False,
                           )
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'required':True,#set attributes
                                                        'class':'form-control',
                                                        'placeholder':'Confirm Password *',
                                                        }),
                            strip=False,
                           )
    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email','first_name','last_name','gender')

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = UserChangeForm.Meta.fields
```

My admin.py looks like:

```
# Register your models here.
# users/admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser



class CustomUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = CustomUser
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm

admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

When I try to register a superuser, through command:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

all the required fields are prompted, after completing all the fields, Django returns an error. (see figure below.)

```
(personalAppEnv) PS C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\django projects\personalApp\personalApp> python manage.py createsuperuser

Email: super@test.com
First name: Super
Last name: User
Gender: 1
Password:
Password (again):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\django 
  projects\personalApp\personalAppEnv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in 
    execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\django 
  projects\personalApp\personalAppEnv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\django 
  projects\personalApp\personalAppEnv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\django 
  projects\personalApp\personalAppEnv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 59, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\django 
  projects\personalApp\personalAppEnv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\django 
  projects\personalApp\personalAppEnv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 184, in handle

    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(
    **user_data)
  TypeError: create_superuser() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'firstName' and 'lastName'
  (personalAppEnv) PS C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\django projects\personalApp\personalApp>
```

Also, when navigating to the signUp form through the browser and sumbitting the form, returns nothing. The form data is not save in the Database, in my views.py I have a line to check if the form is valid -, `form.is_valid()` this returns `True`. see views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm #import signUpForm class to pass to template.

# Create your views here.
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.cleaned_data.get('first_name'))
            form = CustomUserCreationForm()
            return render(request, 'winston/signup.html', {'signUpForm':form,})
        else:
            print('Not Valid!')
            return render(request, 'winston/signup.html', {'signUpForm':form,})
```

I ran: `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` which returned:

[image]

and

[image]

I noticed, after running makemigrations and migrate, the db.sqlite3-journal file does not close. This could be the reason that the database does not update. I think something might be wrong with the model.

if some could give me an explanation or a solution to my peroblem would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add the code into the question rather than linking to pastebins that might not exist in the future. And please copy paste the log output into the question as well, rather than screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the issue,
I changed some arguments in the models.py file. As you can see in models.py in the CustomUser class I used class attributes last_name and first_name, while in the class manager I used firstName and lastName. I'm not sure why this would make a difference but it seemed to have changed something as now users and superusers are being save to the database.